# How to get ShopId in a multi vendor ASP.NET Core 6 application?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-6.0, c#-10.0

I'm using Entity Framework.

```
public class Store : IEntity<Guid>
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Handle { get; set; } //sub-domain
    public string StoreName { get; set; }
    public string? StoreUrl { get; set; } //main url            
}
```

This is the `StoreDbContext`

```
public class StoreDbContext : DbContext, IStoreDbContext
    {
        private readonly string _connectionString;
        private readonly string _assemblyName;

        public StoreDbContext(string connectionString, string assemblyName)
        {
            _connectionString = connectionString;
            _assemblyName = assemblyName;
        }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                optionBuilder.UseSqlServer(_connectionString, m => m.MigrationsAssembly(_assemblyName));
            }

            base.OnConfiguring(optionBuilder);
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
            //many to many(prodcut to category)
            modelBuilder.Entity<ProductCategory>().HasKey(c => new { c.ProductId, c.CategoryId });
        
        public DbSet<STORE> Stores { get; set; }
    }
```

I have created a `StoreInfoService`. Here, I want to get `StoreId` via this method `GetStoreId()`. What should be my process?

Comment: Your question is not clear. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Your question is not clear, Where is `GetStoreId`? and how are you implementing your `StoreInforService` ... Does it retrieve data from `DbContext` ? C'mon give us some details to work with.

Comment: Store InfoService, GetStoreId is empty. Btw... yeah it does retrive from StoreDbContext